# Reg Ex - not allowing zero

Tags: regex, validation

Excuse my ignorance. My knowledge of regular expressions is extremely limited.

I have the following regular expression on a regular expression validator.

```
^(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?){0,2}\d{3}|\d{1,3})$
```

It currently allows zero. I need to update it so that it does not allow a value of 0.

[Edit: Just to clarify, I would like it to exclude a value of zero rather than a singular "0" - thanks]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
zaps

Comment: Just add `(?!0$)` right after `^`

Comment: Or change the second half of the regex to `[1-9]\d{0,2}` See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\d*|(,\d{3})*)$
```

Comment: Replace `\d{1,2}` with `\d{0,2}` and it’s perfect.

Comment: The original regex only allows values up to 999,999,999,999. This one will allow any number > 0. So `^[1-9]\d{1,2}(\d{0,9}|(,\d{3}){0,3})$` might be better. If that requirement is still there.

Comment: @Gumbo: done, thanks.
@Tim: There are more differences.   I was guessing those were unintentional.

Answer (score 3):

`0` is allowed by the second part of your regex. Change it to:

```
^(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?){0,2}\d{3}|[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

It makes sure that the first digit is non zero, when the total number of digits are less than or equal to three.

The regex still allows patterns like `000,000,000` and `000,123` To fix that you can change the first part of the regex to:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2},?(\d{3},?){0,2}\d{3}|[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

Or rewrite it as

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3}){0,3}$
```

This still allows `123,456789` and `123456,789`. Let us change it to:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(,\d{3}){0,3}|(\d{3}){0,3})$
```

This will allow `123,456,789` and `123456789` but not `123,456789` or `123456,789`

Comment: Doesn't this also eliminate, e.g., xy0 or x0y?

Comment: Wrong results.  The intent is not to allow numbers with leading 0s.  You're excluding too much.

Comment: The original question only asks how to disallow "0"s, it makes no mention of "leading" anything.

Comment: No, it asks how to disallow 0, singular. Leading one to conclude that it is the value zero which needs to be excluded. You are correct, however, in that the OP could have included some additional info.

Comment: @Timo I think that's open to interpretation - OP hasn't clarified it.

Comment: @Timo So true, especially considering it's 8 PM here and I'm still in my office refreshing questions page in SO.